# The following `from` values were not present in `x`: mean - Coding R

Tags: r

I am trying to make an R program that will make a dataplot of the nutrients in leaf decay over time. I'm working in Visual Studio if that matters, but I have the same issue in the R executable. I'm using R 4.3.2. I've made this code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(patchwork)
library(Rmisc)

Nutrient_data <- read.csv("C:\\Users\\MyName\\Downloads\\Nutrient_data.csv")

Nitrite_plotdat <- Nutrient_data %>% filter(Site=="Nitrite")
Orthophosphate_plotdat <- Nutrient_data %>% filter(Site=="Orthophosphate")

Nitrite_plotdat <- summarySE(data = Nitrite_plotdat, measurevar = "Quality", groupvars = "Site", na.rm = TRUE)
Orthophosphate_plotdat <- summarySE(data = Orthophosphate_plotdat, measurevar = "Quality", groupvars = "Site", na.rm = TRUE)

p_Nitrite <- ggplot(Nitrite_plotdat, aes(x = Site, y = Nitrite)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Nitrite - se, ymax = Nitrite + se), width = 0.2) + 
  theme_classic()

p_Orthophosphate <- ggplot(Orthophosphate_plotdat, aes(x = Site, y = Orthophosphate)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Orthophosphate - se, ymax = Orthophosphate + se), width = 0.2) + 
  theme_classic()

combined_plot <- p_Nitrite + p_Orthophosphate
combined_plot


# n_model <- aov(nitrate_sum$Quality~nitrite_sum$Site)
# summary(n_model)
# o_model<- aov(orthophosphate_sum$Quality~orthophosphate_sum$Site)
# summary(o_model)
```

I get errors on lines 11 and 12 as following:

```
> Nitrite_plotdat <- summarySE(data = Nitrite_plotdat, measurevar = "Quality",$
The following `from` values were not present in `x`: mean
> Orthophosphate_plotdat <- summarySE(data = Orthophosphate_plotdat, measureva$
The following `from` values were not present in `x`: mean
```

There are no actual errors in my code from what I can see, I get those errors when I run the code. I get a graph with the proper x and y axis but no plotted points.

Here is a tidbit of my CSV for those who need / want to replicate this:

```
Day,Group,Site,Nitrite,Orthophosphate,,SE Nitrite,SE Orthophosphate,,,SD Nitrite,SD Orthophosphate

Monday,1,Townhouse_pond,0.002,0.37,,0.000812409,0.153933338,,,0.005914424,1.088473073

Monday,1,St_Johns_upstream,0.001,0.21,,,,,,,

Monday,1,St_Johns_downstream,0.007,0.11,,,,,,,

Monday,2,Townhouse_pond,0.002,0.53,,,,,,,

Monday,2,St_Johns_upstream,0.003,0.23,,,,,,,

Monday,2,St_Johns_downstream,0.003,0.17,,,,,,,

Monday,3,Townhouse_pond,0.005,0.56,,,,,,,

Monday,3,St_Johns_upstream,0.009,0.2,,,,,,,

Monday,3,St_Johns_downstream,0.016,0.24,,,,,,,

Monday,4,Townhouse_pond,0.013,0.57,,,,,,,

Monday,4,St_Johns_upstream,0.007,0.19,,,,,,,

Monday,4,St_Johns_downstream,0.01,0.17,,,,,,,

Tuesday am,1,Townhouse_pond,0.001,0.57,,,,,,,

Tuesday am,1,St_Johns_upstream,0.009,6.3,,,,,,,
```

I've fixed everything I could and made sure I have the proper imports and libraries. Any further advice and/or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow. I may be overlooking something but in this line `Nitrite_plotdat <- Nutrient_data %>% filter(Site=="Nitrite")` you are filtering for where the site is "Nitrite", but from the sample data you shared "Nitrite" is not a possible site value.

It will be better to share a sample of your data with `dput(head(Nutrient_data, 15))` as it is easier to reproduce in R.

Comment: @JayBee I apologize if I'm mistaken, but column D of my CSV file is nitrite. Nonetheless I tried inputting your suggestion as following I also changed the column to 1 - 16 also to no avail. The console outputs are however much more promising, but my graph is blank.

I now get the following errors:

```
?[1m?[33mError?[39m in `geom_errorbar()`:?[22m
?[1m?[22m?[33m!?[39m Problem while computing aesthetics.
?[36mi?[39m Error occurred in the 2nd layer.
?[1mCaused by error:?[22m
?[33m!?[39m object 'se' not found
?[90mRun `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.?[39m
>
```

Comment: Your line `filter(Site=="Nitrite")` is saying: from dataset Nutrient_data, remove all cases where the `Site` column does not equal value "Nitrite". Is this what you are intending to do? If you don't share the output of `dput(head(Nutrient_data, 15))` it's not possible to provide further help.

Comment: No, that is not what I have intended to do. I apologize for not including the output, there is quite a small word limit here that makes that hard. In essence the code is making two graphs, one for nitrite and one for orthophosphate. Here is some of the output:
```
"St_Johns_downstream", "Townhouse_pond"), Nitrite = c(0.002,
0.001, 0.007, 0.002, 0.003, 0.003, 0.005, 0.009, 0.016, 0.013,
0.007, 0.01, 0.001, 0.009, 0.006, NA), Orthophosphate = c(0.37,
``` 
If youd like, I can email you the output. I also get this error:

Comment: ```
 Nitrite_plotdat <- summarySE(data = Nitrite_plotdat, measurevar = "Quality",$
Error in `[.data.frame`(xx, , col) : undefined columns selected
```
And thats coming from this:
``` 
Nitrite_plotdat <- dput(head(Nutrient_data, 16))
```

Comment: Best is to update the question to include the output of that dput() line.